# @AppStorage property wrapper not able to be toggled with VoiceOver

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover, property-wrapper

I am trying to use a new @property wrapper in iOS 14 @AppStorage. It how ever doesn't seem to be able to be toggled with VoiceOver if I use it in a toggle. A normal @State private var property works fine. I can confirm that these work with VoiceOver not on.

1. Is this an accessibility issue that I can solve myself?
2. Is this a iOS14 bug that Apple needs to fix?

Code below:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

final class Settings: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("sounds") var sounds: Bool = true

    init() {}
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings: Settings
    @State private var sounds: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                VStack {
                    Toggle("AppStore toggle", isOn: $settings.sounds)
                    Toggle("State toggle", isOn: $sounds)
                }
            } .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
// end list
        } // end NavigationView
    } // end body
} // end SettingsView
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be in view

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage("sounds") var sounds: Bool = true     // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                VStack {
                    Toggle("AppStore toggle", isOn: $sounds)
    // ...
```

Comment: So can I not have it in the class at all? I want to be able to access the settings elsewhere.

Comment: You can do that in a class by UserDefaults (which is also a class), the `@AppStore` property modifier is to make it easier to access in SwiftUI views (which are structs).